# Chaining Comparator.thenComparing() does not compile

Tags: java, comparator

Given this class

```java
public abstract class TLog<T> implements Serializable, Comparable<TLog> {
    private LocalDateTime moment;
    private String origin;
    private String type;
    private TableName table; // This is a simple enum
    private Comparator<TLog> comparator;
    private T message; // Message's type defined in child classes
    
    public TLog() {
        // comparator initialization
    }

    /* Getters & Setters omitted */

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TLog other) {
        return comparator.compare(this, other);
    }
}
```

This `Comparator` initialization does compile

```java
this.comparator = Comparator.comparing(TLog::getMoment);
this.comparator = this.getComparator()
    .thenComparing(TLog::getTable)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getOrigin)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getType);
```

But this one doesn't

```java
this.comparator = Comparator.comparing(TLog::getMoment)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getTable)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getOrigin)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getType);
```

And I don't understand why.
Here's the related compilation error on `Comparator.comparing()`

> Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

***Edit 1 :*** Hard-typing `comparing` does work

```java
this.comparator = Comparator.<TLog, LocalDateTime>comparing(TLog::getMoment)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getTable)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getOrigin)
    .thenComparing(TLog::getType);
```

But I still don't get why my previous implementation doesn't work

Comment: Side note : I hope you are aware you are using raw `Log` type in member variable and in implementation of `Comparable`.

Comment: @michalk can you explain how this does impact my implementation. I use generic type  for non listed field (and not used in my comparator).

Comment: This example will not even compile as you have your `compareTo` method done wrong. It is not overriding the method from the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: @michalk excuse me ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
Signature of `Comparable<T>` is `int compareTo(T o)`

Comment: Now after you changed it it will at least compile.

Comment: Why is this class generic when the type parameter `T` is not used anywhere? When you declare a type parameter, you must use it, otherwise, you’ll get the problems explained in [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2711488)

Comment: @Holger I omitted them for brevity, they are used in a field with a related getter & setter.

Comment: @Holger I know that default type is set to Object, my question here is on my `Comparator` which should work without any explicit declaration as it doesn't use my generic `T`. The first comparator will not compile without an explicit type declaration of (raw as it might be any type) `TLog`.

Comment: You *believe* “that default type is set to Object”, but that’s not what raw types are about. In fact there is not even a thing like “default type” in Java’s Generics. That’s why you should read the linked Q&A. Especially the point “*Essentially, raw types behaves just like they were before generics were introduced*”. It doesn’t matter whether it uses `T` or not. You can not expect generic type inference to work when you use a raw type. When the actual type argument doesn’t matter, specify a wildcard type, `<?>`, but don’t use a raw type.

Comment: @Holger specifying `Comparator<TLog<?>>` doesn't fix my error, I still need to specify `comparing` type with `<TLog<?>, LocalDateTime>comparing(TLog::getMoment)`. I admit that it's a cleaner implementation but it doesn't fix the compilation.
I still do not understand why I have to hard-type `comparing()`.

Comment: `Comparator<TLog<?>> comparator = Comparator.comparing(TLog<?>::getMoment) .thenComparing(TLog::getTable) .thenComparing(TLog::getOrigin) .thenComparing(TLog::getType);`

Comment: Nope `Unexpected wildcard` on `comparing(TLog<?>::getMoment)`

Comment: [No compiler errors](https://ideone.com/nS9kAC)

Comment: It does compile, Intellij highlight an error but there's none.
You should post it as an answer :)